# I am coding in android studio and I need to use Http url connection instead of httpclient. How do i convert my code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I need help transfering my code from http client to http URL connection because android studio does not support Http client and it keeps giving me an error. I am using the bing faces api and this api has some particular formatting that needs to be done like sending a header or a body and I don't know if Http url connections supports that or not.

```
    package com.example.test.bingfacessimilar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");


            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect");

            builder.setParameter("returnFaceId", "true");
            builder.setParameter("returnFaceLandmarks", "true");
            builder.setParameter("returnFaceAttributes", "{string}");

            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "77c634fea67944ad861e73ef737bba4b\n");


            // Request body
            StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{\n" + "\"url\":\"http://tamildownloads.p4o.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/rajinipic.jpg?ckattempt=1\"\n" + "}");
            request.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to switch from httpclient to http urlconnection. You will have to rewrite your code. For reference, see the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

However if you still want to use httpclient, then do the following.

Add useLibrary ‘org.apache.http.legacy’ in your build.gradle file as below-

```
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

If this does not work do the following

– Copy org.apache.http.legacy.jar which is in /platforms/android-23/optional path of your Android SDK directory to your project’s app/libs folder.

– Now Add compile files(‘libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar’) inside dependencies{} section of build.gradle file.